# Binary mode in FTP?

Tags: ftp, base64

The binary mode in FTP transfers data as raw bits. This raised a doubt for me recently when I was reading about Base64 encoding. The whole point of Base64 is to convert binary to text and it makes a lot of sense. Because the binary could be interpreted as some special character / command by some media in the middle.

So does the binary mode transfer raw binary? Or does it do some kind of encoding before transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to telnet or SMTP (mail) connections the binary mode FTP data channel does not interpret any octets in a special way, so no encoding or escaping is necessary.